# How to tranform data from a collection to an another collection with condition by MongoDB query?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a "voice" collection, with with the data field "originaltimestamp" of the form timestamp yyyy.mm.dd.hh:mm:ss (eg 20200113033803 means 13/01/2020 at 03:38:03). The data of this collection has the following form:

**Voice collection (Have 4 documents)**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5cbf38"),
    "subscriber_id" : "e3365edb9c781a561107242a81c1a92b4269ef9a",
    "callednumber" : "559198e6f8814773551a457e53a614d603f9deab",
    "originaltimestamp" : "20200113033803", // It’s means 13/01/2020 at 03:38:03).
    "duration" : "13",
    "maincost" : "255.6",
    "type" : "Internal",
    "type_network" : "local_network",
    "month" : "202001"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5cbf39"),
    "subscriber_id" : "6cf5d711bfa12160eefe62b8bc9c914370eebd70",
    "callednumber" : "0241052d42e5491b0529733716fb6fb04804248f",
    "originaltimestamp" : "20200113041608", //It’s mean 13/01/2020 at 04:16:08
    "duration" : "28",
    "maincost" : "644.0",
    "type" : "Internal",
    "type_network" : "global_network",
    "month" : "202001"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5ccaf0"),
    "subscriber_id" : "8b660764166c2fb29e513321ff40a4f914d3f92f",
    "callednumber" : "6b1c5f80c620c12e5d86b5217371116f49798c01",
    "originaltimestamp" : "20200111084941", //It’s mean 11/01/2020 at 08:49:41
    "duration" : "29",
    "maincost" : "333.5",
    "type" : "Internal",
    "type_network" : "local_network",
    "month" : "202001"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5ccaf1"),
    "subscriber_id" : "3ccf5bf52cfd1f07a8e8458c39ddd51ee72980dd",
    "callednumber" : "1c78798ad32a614bbd2073a63025879312911c25",
    "originaltimestamp" : "20200111085042",  //It’s mean 11/01/2020 at 08:50:42
    "duration" : "74",
    "maincost" : "2194.9",
    "type" : "Internal",
    "type_network" : "global_network",
    "month" : "202001"
}
```

Now I want to transform this collection into a new collection named "dailyvoice" that only stores transactions by date (dailly). This way, the new collection I will reduce the number of documents (records) and I can easily query the transactions by date. As the example above the collection "voice" has all 4 documents (including 2 documents for 11/01/2020 and 2 documents for 01/13/2020, now the collection "daillyvoice" has only 2 records left.

The new collection will look like this:

**DailyVoice (Now only have 2 documents)**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5ccaf4"),
     "13012020": [
             {
      "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5cbf38"),
      "subscriber_id" : "e3365edb9c781a561107242a81c1a92b4269ef9a",
      "callednumber" : "559198e6f8814773551a457e53a614d603f9deab",
      "originaltimestamp" : "20200113033803", // It’s means 13/01/2020 at 03:38:03).
      "duration" : "13",
      "maincost" : "255.6",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "type_network" : "local_network",
      "month" : "202001"
               }, 
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5cbf39"),
      "subscriber_id" : "6cf5d711bfa12160eefe62b8bc9c914370eebd70",
      "callednumber" : "0241052d42e5491b0529733716fb6fb04804248f",
      "originaltimestamp" : "20200113041608", //It’s mean 13/01/2020 at 04:16:08
      "duration" : "28",
      "maincost" : "644.0",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "type_network" : "global_network",
      "month" : "202001"
  }
]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5ccafb"),
     "11012020": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5ccaf0"),
            "subscriber_id" : "8b660764166c2fb29e513321ff40a4f914d3f92f",
            "callednumber" : "6b1c5f80c620c12e5d86b5217371116f49798c01",
            "originaltimestamp" : "20200111084941", //It’s mean 11/01/2020 at 08:49:41
            "duration" : "29",
            "maincost" : "333.5",
            "type" : "Internal",
            "type_network" : "local_network",
            "month" : "202001"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612599bb1cff80e6fc5ccaf1"),
            "subscriber_id" : "3ccf5bf52cfd1f07a8e8458c39ddd51ee72980dd",
            "callednumber" : "1c78798ad32a614bbd2073a63025879312911c25",
            "originaltimestamp" : "20200111085042",  //It’s mean 11/01/2020 at 08:50:42
            "duration" : "74",
            "maincost" : "2194.9",
            "type" : "Internal",
            "type_network" : "global_network",
            "month" : "202001"
        }
]
}
```

I've tried this query, but maybe it's have something wrong in originaltimestamp

```
db.getCollection('voice').aggregate(
  [ 
  { 
      "$project": {
       "date": { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$originaltimestamp" ] },
       "subscriber_id":1,
       "callednumber":1,
       "originaltimestamp":1,
       "duration": 1,
       "maincost": 1,
       "type": 1,
       "type_network": 1,
       "month":1
  }},
 
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$originaltimestamp" } },
    "data": { $push: "$$ROOT" } ,
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
  ,
  {
   '$out': 'dailyvoice' // create new collection here
  }
]
)
```

I don't know how to combine all transactions of the same date into one array? And how to save it to another table named "DailyVoice". What query can do this?
Please take a look. Thanks you so much

Comment: The general approach would be to use aggregation grouping by day - use aggregation operators to work with the timestamp data (refer the MongoDB Manual).

Comment: I already tried group by day (by originaltimestamp field) but the querry is not work.

Comment: You have to extract the _day_ aspect from the timestamp. If you had tried, include that code in your question post.

Comment: Since it's not worked yet, I don't want to post it in the question, but because of your request, I've updated my querry my question. Please correct it for me. Thanks

Comment: You can use `$push` (aggregate operator) in the `$group` stage to include some data into an array.

Comment: Can you correct me? I got following error: Failed to execute script.

Error:
Uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $add only supports numeric or date types, not string",
 "code" : 16554,
 "codeName" : "Location16554"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:583:17
I think I have to convert  readable timestamp in format of, yyyymmddHHMMSS to number?

Comment: The error is due to the reason that `originaltimestamp` is a string type in your document. I think you should know that you use `$add` operator to add numbers (or dates in some cases).

Comment: I was wrong at $project step, after convert readable timestamp to date, it's worked. Anyway, thanks you